# Axios with promise.prototype.finally doesn't work

Tags: javascript, promise, axios

Not sure what I am missing. Following the instructions here: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/blob/master/COOKBOOK.md

I have npm installed both axios and `npm install axios promise.prototype.finally --save`.

I am using Gulp with Browserify.

```
var axios = require('axios');
require('promise.prototype.finally');

axios.get('http://google.com').finally(function(){
    console.log('test');
});
```

Error:

```
app-7ee90adab7.js:18780 Uncaught TypeError: axios.get(...).finally is not a function
```

Update:
This makes it work but do I need to do this?

```
var promiseFinally = require('promise.prototype.finally');
promiseFinally.shim();
```

Comment: Does axios use native promises or its own implementation? Try `Promise.resolve(axios.get(…)).finally(…)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of these see if it works:

1. See if you have a global Promise available to shim it? Enter `Promise` in chrome console while the browserify is running the bundle. If you don't have it, use Babel or a lib that makes es6 or just Promise available.
2. If it didn't work for some reason... well axios cookbook.md didn't get it right, since you have to call shim() to apply it on promise proto. why don't you use a shorthand `require('promise.prototype.finally').shim();` if you don't like it that way, otherwise you have to `require('es6-shim');`

Comment: 1. Promise does return ```function Promise() { [native code] }``` but browserify is used in a gulp task. I am not sure if you mean browserify in the browser. 2. I went with the shorthand.

Comment: Hm, this doesn't seem to work for me. I've installed `promise.prototype.finally` and used the shorthand in the answer above but get the error `Property 'finally' does not exist on type Promise<void>`

Answer (score 4):

FYI https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/34#issuecomment-558869934
Axios supports `.finally()`.